# Need help in choosing correct data structure

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures

I am having below data in key value format, first I want to sum up the Amount by CustomerID and then sort by Amount in descending order.

```
`
public class Customer
{
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
}

List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>()
{
    new Customer{
        CustomerId ="C1",
        Amount = 10
    },
    new Customer{
        CustomerId ="C2",
        Amount = 20
    },
    new Customer{
        CustomerId ="C1",
        Amount = 30
    },
    new Customer{
        CustomerId ="C3",
        Amount = 30
    },
    new Customer{
        CustomerId ="C4",
        Amount = 5
    }
};
`
```

In the final output I want to categorized the customers with top 25% maximum values, next 25% max values and rest customers.

Here expected output is:-

In Top 25%, Customer C1 comes with amount 40
Next 25 % , Customer C3 comes with amount 30
In rest Customer C2 and C4 comes.

I tried to solve this problem using List and Dictionary, but input data is too huge so it is taking long time to execute the the code. Also Dictionary is taking large memory for this code. I wanted to know what is the best data structure for this problem.

Comment: We need to see a [mcve] before we can suggest improvements.  Your performance problems may be the result of an inefficient algorithm, in which case changing data structures probably won't help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have to have `List` of customer or not.

But if I have flow where you are getting `Customer` one by one and you need to store the data somewhere, I would implement a data structure something like below.

```
static Dictionary<string, double> customerDataTable = new Dictionary<string, double>();
```

*here instead of `Dictionary<string, double>` you can use `Dictionary<string, Customer>` if you need ready made `Customer` object during the flow.*

and then I would make a method to update this table like

```
    static void UpdateCustomerRecord(string customerId, double amount)
    {
        if (customerDataTable.ContainsKey(customerId))
            customerDataTable[customerId] = customerDataTable[customerId] + amount;
        else
            customerDataTable.Add(customerId, amount); 
    }
```

and calling this method will be as simple as below,

```
UpdateCustomerRecord("c1", 10);
UpdateCustomerRecord("c2", 20);
UpdateCustomerRecord("c1", 30);
UpdateCustomerRecord("c3", 30);
UpdateCustomerRecord("c4", 5);
```

Here you must have note that I have eleminated entier `Customer` class, but if it is not possible in your case, you can implement the same flow with `Customer` class (as I already have mentioned above).

- Here you will not be required to keep the temporary copy of data while you catagorise them (into first 40% and second 40% and so on).
- you can easily use `Linq` on it
- you can easily traverse through Dictionary

based on amount of the data, memory requirement will be there. and that is for sure. to optimise it you can re-think on the data and datatype needed. (ex. if you need amount in full number and that too less then 255, you can use byte instead of double)